# How to convert a text file having a hexadecimal code sequence into a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, byte, text-parsing

So I was wondering if there any possibility to read a plain text bytes sequence in hexadecimal from a text file?

**The Bytes Are Saved On to A Text File in Text Format**

e.g. :

```
string text = 
  @"0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00";
```

Here I *don't mean* `File.ReadAllBytes(filename)`

What I tried is reading the text file with `File.ReadAllText(filename)` but sadly thats in a string `Format` not in the `byte` format...

We need to convert these *text sequence* to a `byte` array.

These text sequence are actual bytes stored in a text file.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Just for clarity: does file include the commas and spaces as shown? Any line breaks?

Comment: Are you being pranked? Whoever gave you this cannot be serious.

Comment: For reference, that is almost certainly _not_ a text file.  Looks like the beginnings of an exe.

Comment: yes file does include commas and spaces. yes after every 12 comma there is a line break

Comment: Oh, so the file is those actual characters ( ie: a text editor shows you "0x4D, 0x5A, ..."), and you have to convert the text to a sequence of bytes?

Comment: Dimitry i already stated above the strings are the actual bytes... we cant use encoding there

Comment: cHao yes bro thats what i need

Comment: Need to clarify that, then.  I (and i'm sure others) have been assuming you're listing out the literal byte values in the file, and that's a very different question.

Comment: Can we all just quietly agree that whoever devised this file needs to be stared at mercilessly until they ask why, and then be educated?

Comment: cHao yes dude the text sequence listed in the text file are actual bytes... and i need a method in **C#** to read those as  byte array from the text file.

Comment: @MarcGravell Had to read your comment 3x and now I am laughing tears. Excellent suggestion, though! Let's do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have a `string` like this

```
  string text =
    @"0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00";
```

and you want to obtain `byte[]` (array). If it's your case, you can try *matching* with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 

  ...

  byte[] result = Regex
    .Matches(text, @"0x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}")     // 0xH or 0xHH where H is a hex digit
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => Convert.ToByte(m.Value, 16)) // convert each match to byte
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var result = 
    File.ReadAllText(filename)
   .Split(',')
   .Select(item => byte.Parse(item.Trim().Substring(2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
   .ToArray();
```